# create a 16:9 view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing a program that I would like to have a 16:9 screen all the time.  I set up a basic linearlayout to host 2 object that I write.  The first one overwrite the onMeasure method, so that it'll take a "square" space from the screen, and the second object take the rest.  This looks good on a 16:9 device that I have.  But when I tried it out on other device, it just looks bad.  I tried to extend from the linearlayout that host my object, and overwrite the onMeasure method for the layout.  The custom Linearlayout seems to do the 16:9 fine, but my first object (the square), is still getting the big square, not a smaller square confined to the 16:9 strip.  Here are the relavent code

MainActivity:
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    layout = new MyLinear(this);

    mField = new Field(this);
    mField.setId(1);

    control = new Controller(this);
    control.setId(2);

    layout.addView(mField);

    layout.addView(control);
    registerForContextMenu(control);

    setContentView(layout);
    mField.requestFocus();

}
```

the onMeasure code for the custom linearlayout looks like this

```
public class MyLinear extends LinearLayout{

private int height, width; // dimension of the screen
private Context m_context;

public MyLinear(Context context) {
    super(context);
    m_context=context;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int height_temp = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int width_temp = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    double ratio = width_temp/(double)height_temp;
    int final_height = (int) (width_temp/1.77);
    height=final_height;

    if (ratio<1.7) {
      setMeasuredDimension(width_temp, (int) (width_temp/1.77));

    } else {
      setMeasuredDimension(width_temp, height_temp);
    }

}
```

anyone has a better suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you take some time and accept some of the answers you asked before if they helped.

Answer (score 0):

You edit, view.xml file. Add res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml folder. after add my_layout.xml file res/layout-xlarge/ folder... I'm sorry for bad english